# MySQL: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

```
this is my log

2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
***MySQL: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist***
**2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.**
2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-10-01 23:23:56 5404 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-10-01 23:23:57 5404 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-10-01 23:23:57 5404 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-10-01 23:23:57 5404 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 1600627
2017-10-01 23:23:57 5404 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-10-01 23:23:57 5404 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-10-01 23:23:57 5404 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-10-01 23:23:57 5404 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
**2017-10-01 23:23:57 5404 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist**
```

I am installed in the win10 environment,
I have tried to update it with **mysql_upgrade -u root - p**, but at this point it prompts me for a password error, but my password is not wrong, and I save it in my notepad.I have read a lot of information but still haven't solved it. What should I do

Comment: If you need help resetting the root password, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Do you have a space in between `- p`? That's wrong, it must be together like `-p`.

Comment: Not for this reason, I still haven't solved the problem

Comment: Also see https://ma.ttias.be/mysql-table-mysql-plugin-doesnt-exist-after-mysql-upgrade/